# How to configure two versions of tomcat to run on port 8080 only one at a time

Tags: tomcat, server

At this point I could configure to run two versions of tomcat (8 and 9) to run on different HTTP ports Z and Z+1. What I did was

1. Having two separate systemd unit files as tomcat.service and tomcat9.service below to their own
   destinations in two files.

1. Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
2. Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
3. Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat

2. Changed the ports for two instances:

1. Server port="Y and Y+1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"
2. Connector port="Z and Z+1" protocol="HTTP/1.1"connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="B and B+1"
3. Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" address="::1" port="8010" redirectPort="B and B+1"

I could run the two instances simultaneously. But now I want both instances to have the same Z port and **only one instance is guaranteed** to run at anytime.Have I missed any configurations?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224022/381289) on UNIX StackExchange to properly configure the two services. BTW: to obtain the configuration you show in your question, you can also use `portOffset="1"` on your `<Server>` element.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Piotr P. Karwasz, I added the Conflicts=otherservicename.service under [Unit] section so it stops what ever the other service is hanged on to which stops the current one to run incorrectly.

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=tomcat9.service
```